# Задача на функциональные интерфейсы java 8

Tags: java

Не могу решить задачу из базового курса java. Задача на функциональные интерфейсы  которые добавлены в java 8, поэтому думаю много кому будет полезно. Дан предикат condition и две функции ifTrue и ifFalse. Напишите метод ternaryOperator, который из них построит новую функцию, возвращающую значение функции ifTrue, если предикат выполнен, и значение ifFalse иначе.

```
public static <T, U> Function<T, U> ternaryOperator(
        Predicate<? super T> condition,
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> ifTrue,
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> ifFalse) {

    return null; // your implementation here

}
```

Пример использования метода:

```
Predicate<Object> condition = Objects::isNull;
Function<Object, Integer> ifTrue = obj -> 0;
Function<CharSequence, Integer> ifFalse = CharSequence::length;
Function<String, Integer> safeStringLength = ternaryOperator(condition, ifTrue, ifFalse);
```

Результирующая функция будет для нулевых ссылок на String возвращать 0, а для ненулевых ссылок возвращать длину строки.
Т.е. к примеру `Integer a = safeStringLength.apply("aaa")` должно вернуть 3,
а `Integer a = safeStringLength.apply(null)` должно вернуть 0.

javadoc интерфейсов тут http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/function/package-summary.html.

Т.е. насколько я понимаю нужно взять объект переданый в наш `Function<T, U>` ( в данном случае это строка "ааа" и передать его в condition.Test() Если  `condition.Test(T t)= true`  то возвращаем ifTrue, иначе ifFalse.Т.к. тут еще джинерики замешаны все мои попытки подчеркивает компилятор). Есть идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static <T, U> Function<T, U> ternaryOperator(
        Predicate<? super T> condition,
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> ifTrue,
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> ifFalse) {

    return t -> condition.test(t) ? ifTrue.apply(t) : ifFalse.apply(t);

}
```

Объяснять нужно или сами разберетесь?

```
condition::test :: T -> Bool
ifTrue::apply :: T -> U
ifFalse::apply :: T -> U
```

Comment: Спасибо понятно, Да реализация простая, но немного сложное для понимания

Comment: Маленькое t откуда здесь?

Comment: от пользователя, по условию задачи "метод ternaryOperator, который из них построит новую функцию".  значит нам надо возвращать либо (как в другом ответе-дубликате) new Function<T,U> либо лямбду из T в U, как я.